# MySQL garbage collect memory tables

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use tables with engine=memory in MySQL it destroys performance on the rest of my machine.  Is there a way to garbage collect the tables when I'm done with them so I don't have to restart my machine?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying you're not dropping the tables yourself ? (or are you declaring them as temp tables, but using e.g. connection pooling ?)

Comment: I drop them myself but it doesn't seem to free the memory up for other programs.